# I'm making a tuple class in C++11 using variadic templates. How do I work with its instance variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, variadic-templates

So say I define a tuple as such:

```
template<typename... Args>
class Tuple 
{
    Method () {...};
};
```

How do I define and access the instance variables for Tuple considering it can have an undefined number of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways. The easiest one is to use structural recursion the way LISP does: a tuple is either

- an empty tuple, or
- a pair `(head, tail)` where `head` is the first element of the tuple and `tail` is a tuple containing the rest of the elements.

In C++, this would look like the following:

```
template <typename... Elems>
struct tuple; // undefined

template <>
struct tuple<> { }; // empty tuple

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct tuple<Head, Tail...> {
    Head first_elem;
    tuple<Tail...> rest;
};
```

Then you need a `get<n>` function template to actually access the elements by index; it should be rather easy to implement if you grok how the tuple itself is recursively defined.

As I said, there are other, trickier, implementation methods - for various reasons the above is not how most real-world `std::tuple` implementations do it.

Comment: Actually, that *is* how they do it. The nonstatic members may be replaced by base class subobjects, though, for the empty base optimization.

Comment: That's a useful explanation. Any further description of these optimizations or direction to reference material on the subject would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be curious to see the get<N> function written out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use boost tuple library - simple to use, well tested and documented:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html